# PRC analysis with paired observations in vegan

Tags: r, vegan

This message is a copy from a message that I wrote in R-Forge. I would like to compute Principal response curve analysis on my data. I have several pairs of plots where deer browse the vegetation on Anticosti island, Québec. There are repeated observations of each plot during the course of 4 years. At each site, there is a plot inside the enclosure (without deer, called "exclosure") and the other plot is outside the enclosure (with deer, called "control"). I would like to take into account the pairing of observations in and out of each enclosure in the PRC analysis. I would like to add an other condition term to the PRC (like in partial RDA) to consider the paired observations or extract value from a partial RDA computed with the PRC formula and plot it like it is done in a PRC.

More over, I would like to test with permutations tests the signification of the difference between the two treatments. My hypothesis is to find if vegetation composition is different in the exclosure than in the control throughout the years. So, I would like to know if there is a difference between the two treatments and if there is, after how many years.

Somebody knows how to do this?

So here the code of my prc (without taking paired observations into account):

```
levels (treat)
[1] "controle" "exclosure"

levels (years)
[1] "0" "3" "5" "8"

prc.out <- prc(data.prc.spe.hell, treat, years)
    species <- colSums(data.prc.spe.hell)
    plot(prc.out, select = species > 5)

ctrl <- how(plots = Plots(strata = site,type = "free"),
            within = Within(type = "series"), nperm = 99)
anova(prc.out, permutations = ctrl, first=TRUE)
```

[Here is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClYWI.jpg)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I may have an answer for the first part of your question:"I would like to add an other condition term to the PRC (like in partial RDA) to consider the paired observations".

I am currently working on a similar case and this is what I came up with: Since Principal Responses Curves (PRC) are a special case of RDA, and that the objective is to do a kind of "partial PRC", I read the R documentation of the function rda() and this is what I found: "If matrix Z is supplied, its effects are removed from the community matrix, and the residual matrix is submitted to the next stage."

So if I understand well, when you do a partial RDA with X, Y, Z (X=community matrix, Y=Constraining matrix, Z=Conditioning matrix), the first thing done by the function is to remove the effect of Z by using the residuals matrix of the RDA of X ~ Z.

If that is true, it is easy to do this step alone, and then to use the residual matrix in your PRC:

```
library(vegan)
rda.out = rda(X ~ Z) # equivalent of "rda.out = rda(X ~ Condition(Z))"
rda.res = residuals(rda.out)
prc.out = prc(rda.res, treatment, time)
```

If you coded a dummy variable for your pairing effect, I think it should be as.factor() and NOT as.numeric().

I am not a stats expert, but it looks right to me. Even though that look simple, I would appreciate if someone could validate my answer.

Cheers